# Reading HDR photo in Android with RGBA_F16 and accessing single pixel from buffer

Tags: android, bitmap, hdr

AFAIK HDR images in PNG are saved as integer values in 16-bit depth. But in Android SDK I can read HDR image with configuration [`Config.RGBA_F16`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.Config#RGBA_F16), which has a very interesting description:

> Each pixels is stored on 8 bytes. Each channel (RGB and alpha for translucency) is stored as a half-precision floating point value. This configuration is particularly suited for wide-gamut and HDR content.

Is single channel of a pixel (e.g. red) stored in 8 bits as in the description, or is it stored in 16 bits as name `RGBA_F16` may suggest?

And the second question is how to get all 4 channels of a single pixel? E.g. where the top-left pixel is stored: at indices `0, 1, 2, 3` or at indices `0, 1*h*w, 2*h*w, 3*w*h`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding number of bits, you are mixing up bits and bytes. Each pixel is stored in 8 bytes using 16-bit format. There is no contradiction here, as each pixel has 4 channels, which are stored in 16 bits each. So each each pixel takes up 4*16 = 64 bits of memory, which is the same as 8 bytes.

And for the second question, pixels are stored as consecutive chunks of memory as description of `Config.RGBA_F16` suggest:

```java
long color = (A & 0xffff) << 48 | (B & 0xffff) << 32 | (G & 0xffff) << 16 | (R & 0xffff);
```

This can also be verified in the [source code](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/master:frameworks/base/graphics/java/android/graphics/Bitmap.java;drc=master;l=1917) of `Bitmap.getColor`. It means that the top-left pixel is stored at bytes with indices 0-7.

One thing that I noticed is that you can't get 16-bit pixel channel values using [`Bitmap.getColor`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap#getColor(int,%20int)), because it will convert colors to 8 bits. [`Bitmap.getPixels`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap#getPixels(int%5B%5D,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int)) [converts](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/oreo-release/core/jni/android/graphics/Bitmap.cpp#1385) 16 bits to 8 bits too. Using [`Bitmap.getPixel`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap#getPixel(int,%20int)) doesn't help either, because it returns int.

Therefore the only way to access 16-bit pixels is to use [`Bitmap.copyPixelsToBuffer`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap#copyPixelsToBuffer(java.nio.Buffer)).